# Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

```
Sub amazon()

Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim htmTable As HTMLTable
Dim Elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Element As IHTMLElement
Dim bf As String
Dim str As String
Dim af As String
Dim title As String
Dim prc()
Dim SrtTemp As Variant
Dim i As Long, q As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim n As Long
  n = Sheets("temp").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
For q = 7 To n
    Sheets("temp").Cells(q, 5) = ""
   Sheets("temp").Cells(q, 6) = ""
Next q
str = ""
   str = Sheets("temp").Cells(1, 4)
   With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
     .Open "GET", "http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=sr_nr_n_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A976419031%2Cn%3A1805560031%2Ck%3A" & str & "&keywords=" & str & "&ie=UTF8&qid=1437023564&rnid=976420031", ""
     .send

     Do: DoEvents: Loop Until .readyState = 4
     Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
     doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText

       Set Elements = doc.getElementsByClassName("s-item-container")
       x = Elements.Length
      '' Debug.Print x
       ReDim prc(0 To x)
       z = 7
       y = 0
       For Each Element In Elements
           title = Element.Children(1).innerText
          '' Debug.Print title
           If InStr(UCase(title), UCase(str)) Then
                    Sheets("temp").Cells(z, 5) = title
                    Price = Element.Children(2).Children(0).Children(0).innerText
                    If InStr(UCase(Price), UCase("offer")) = 0 Then

                        bf = Price
                       '' Debug.Print bf
                        prc(y) = Trim(CDbl(bf))
                        On Error Resume Next
                      ''  Debug.Print prc(y)
                        Sheets("temp").Cells(z, 6) = prc(y)
                    Else
             ''    bf = Element.Children(2).Children(3).Children(0).Children(3).innerText
                        bf = Price
                      ''  Debug.Print bf

                        prc(y) = Trim(CDbl(Right(bf, 9)))
                        Sheets("temp").Cells(z, 6) = prc(y)

                      ''  Debug.Print prc(y)
                    End If
                    y = y + 1
                    z = z + 1
           End If
        Next Element
        Set Elements = Nothing

        .abort
        On Error Resume Next
    End With

End Sub
```

When i debug i am getting the error Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set at this line title = Element.Children(1).innerText Please help me to resolve this issue.

I am using amazon as a macro in my Excel worksheet.I am using excel 2016 and when i debug this macro i am getting this error.So please provide a solution to resolve this problem.

If i use Set title = Element.Children(1).innerText then i am getting Object required error.

I am a newbie to Vba so please help me out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if not Element is nothing then
    if not Element.Children(1) is nothing then
        title = Element.Children(1).innerText
    end if
end if
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.